# Cannot boot to Windows 10 in dual-boot setup with Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-10

I've scoured the site and haven't found an issue close enough to this yet.

I recently installed Lubuntu on my Windows 10 device to facilitate coding and receive a lighter desktop environment. The installation went fine, with the exception of two blaring faults:

*When booting, I'm shown Grub with four selections:*

- Ubuntu (boots into Lubuntu just fine)
- Advanced options for Ubuntu (whatever)
- **Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)** (all this does is send me back to Grub)
- System Setup

I followed the guidelines on the Lubuntu site (with some reference to normal Ubuntu setup) to make sure I did the dual-boot properly; sda3 contains my Windows 10 operating system along with the bulk of my files (which are all backed up in hard copies) while sda6 contains my Lubuntu environment.

sda3 (where Windows, my default, was located) is listed as NTFS while sda6 (Lubuntu) is listed as Ext4.

All my previous files are intact exactly where I downloaded them, and I assumed Windows is still there, completely healthy; **but I can't access it!**

*The second complication; I cannot connect to wifi on Lubuntu, rendering me helpless on the computer and unable to even attempt many troubleshoots.*

I have very limited experience with Linux, though I've read up on the command line a lot, and opted for Lubuntu because it can boot with UEFI enabled alongside Win10. However, I am sick of this; I followed all of the steps listed from credible sources and I am now unable to access my chief operating system, which I had no intention of scrapping (hence dual-booting).

I list a lot of minor details because I am not sure what is helpful and what is not; suffice it to say that any solution that can bring Windows 10 into the boot list will be tremendously helpful. I would be fully satisfied completely resetting the computer as it was, with only Windows 10 running and all of my files gone, if that's necessary and if someone can instruct me how (last time I tried it just reinstalled Windows on the partition I can't access and booted into Ubuntu).

I am currently trying "boot-repair" to see if that magically resolves this. If Windows was somehow compromised, I'm also setting up a disc to install the operating system again.

If Windows is somehow no longer functional through all of this, I'd like to know that as well, and will supply whatever information I can glean without an internet connection from the laptop if it is needed for an informed answer.

Again, I just want to access Windows again, even at the expense of this dysfunctional Ubuntu partition.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I managed to reinstall windowa through the boot loader and *accessed it for the first time in a while*. I was so scared out of my mind that I deleted my Ubuntu partition and rebooted with the windows recovery disc to remove grub.  Now there's another problem...

I can't seem to advanced boot with f2,  and get sentto a stripped-down Grub loader: "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported." I want to trash Grub entirely, but to do that I need access to the Windows loader.

If I can replace Grub with the default Windows boot loader, I can stop my hair out and swear to never do anything potentially dangerous to a computer without professional supervision.

Again, I need to delete Grub loader so I can use Windows loader like the machine initially intended,  but I keep getting sent to this minimal BASH-like Grub screen.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Did you leave fast start up or its always on hibernation turned on? Or does it need chkdsk?  Or is Secure boot still on, grub will not chain to Windows with secure boot on. You can from UEFI boot tab or one time boot key, often f10 or f12 check your manual, directly boot Windows. You may need hard wired Ethernet connection to correctly down loader wireless drivers and upload Boot-Repair's Summary report.

Comment: From what I read online initially, the problem seemed to be that Win10 had its default hibernate on. I had secure boot off initially, and flipped it on for a little to see if it'd do anything, but it's currently off. I will try direct boot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. To boot Windows 10 a different way, hit F12 while it is displaying the company's name, then choose Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: Windows Boot Manager is there,  but selecting it only sends me back to Grub.  I'm seriously discouraged to be getting kicked from my job for failing at an Ubuntu distro...

Comment: If you get grub when Booting Windows did you do the old work around or have an old copy of Boot-Repair? That copied grub or shim to Windows own efi boot file as a work around. But is not the current alternative Boot-Repair suggests which is a BCD entry. Or copy grub or shim to bootx64.efi. Best to make sure /EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi is really the Windows copy.